# Hadoop filenames location

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

Good day I'm doing little search about Hadoop file system

I'm looking for this point:

- Hadoop filenames location transparent, or location independent?
- How is replication done in Hadoop, and how is consistency maintained?

Any expert with Hadoop can give some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namenode will store the Filenames, number of replicas, respective block ids ....

Hadoop filename is location transparent since the file contents are distributed.

Replication is performed on the basis of the replication settings for the file(will take the global setting if not set specifically for file). Replication is performed based on  Hadoop replica placement policy

It will update the metadata based on the block reports received from datanodes. In case of not receiving update from datanode it consider the node as failed and replicate the data to another node.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/images/hdfsdatanodes.gif